# How to Run a Kotlin Task from Android Project's build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My project's build.gradle is in Groovy but I'd like to run as a gradle task the main function of a Kotlin class in a root directory kt file.

I don't know where to begin in terms of syntax.

something like this? I came up with this after searching around a bit.

```
task doKotlinTask(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath "/"
  main = "KotlinTaskKt"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create in the root directory `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin` and place `MyKotlinClass.Kt`there. Create `buildSrc/build.gradle` to add any dependencies for MyKotlinClass.

Then in your project or app's build.gradle, append the following:

```
import my.package.for.the.kotlin.class
task doKotlinTask(type: MyKotlinClass) {
  someParamForTheTask = "hello world"
}
```